# MongoServerError: unknown group operator '$top'

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I am using mongoose ORM to query my mongodb database. I am facing an issue when using aggregation. I am a novice at mongodb. I am using this pipeline to filter out chats for a particular user for a chatting application.

```
MongoServerError: unknown group operator '$top'
```

My aggregation query is as below.

```
aggregate([
            {
              $match: {
                users: ObjectId("<UserID>")
              }
            },
            {
              $group: {
                _id: "$users",
                out: {
                  $top: {
                    output: {
                      _id: "$_id",
                      content: "$content",
                      fromUser: "$fromUser",
                      toUser: "$toUser",
                      users: "$users",
                      messageRead: "$messageRead",
                      createdAt: "$createdAt"
                    },
                    sortBy: {
                      createdAt: -1
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "$replaceRoot": {
                "newRoot": "$out"
              }
            }
          ])
```

Comment: What is your mongodb version. `$top` is only available since version 5.2

Comment: I have not installed mongodb locally. I am using it from cloud.mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [@nimrod serok in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73863242/mongoservererror-unknown-group-operator-top#comment130424408_73863242) that the actual error described is almost certainly a version mismatch. Check your cluster's configuration in Atlas to confirm that it is on `6.0`.

That said, I think you may be able to approach the operation entirely differently. If I'm interpreting the aggregation correctly, the intention is to find a single document with a given value for the `users` field which was `createdAt` most recently. If so, then there is no need for the `$group` and subsequent `$replaceRoot` at all.

Instead, just consider doing a `$sort` and then `{$limit: 1}`. If you additionally have an index on `{ users: 1, createdAt: -1 }` then the operation should be very efficient. [Here is a playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XCrd4j21viE) demonstrating the approach.

Somewhat relatedly, it might be worth noting that this alternative approach can be handled with a simple `find()` (with `.sort()` and `.limit()`) rather than using the full aggregation framework. Either should be perfectly acceptable.